# Can Session.Delete the table entry even if the table has a foreign key constraint without delete cascade or null specified

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and I don't understand much with how exactly Hibernate delete and save perform internally.

I had to fix something in the existing code . Tables currently used by the code does have a foreign Key defined but the delete cascade has not been defined on the Table .

Still the existing code does delete the entry from original table.

I am not able to figure out how code is handling it currently . Is it possible to define some hibernate settings for foreign key deletion instead of defining in DB. 
If yes then how .  Any hint would help.

Answer (score 0):

Cascade delete can be defined also in hibernate.

See example (using JPA annotations):

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Address> addresses;
}

@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String cityName;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

}
```

now suppose this code sample:

```
 User user =  entityManager.find(User.class, 1L);
 entityManager.remove(user);
```

Deleting user will trigger cascade delete of associated Addresses.

Be aware of using HQL (or JPQL).It doesn't trigger cascade delete, e.g. entityManager.createQuery("delete User where id=1").executeUpdate() will cause FK reference error probably